# Bootstrap Date to C# Datetime in MVC action

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have C# model class as below.

```
public class Revise
        {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }        
        }
```

In Angular controllers, i have below model

```
$scope.Revise = {
                    Id: '',
                    Name: '',
                    EffectiveStartDate: ''                                   
                };
```

In my View, i am using bootstrap datepicker whose value is binded to the Revise.EffectiveStartDate as below

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" class="form-control  input-sm" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="Revise.EffectiveStartDate"/>
```

Now, when i call api controller action which accepts C# object of type as Revise (defined above), with javascript object created using view, all fields are converted to C# fields properly except EffectiveStartDate where i am getting previous date.

e.g. when i am selecting 26 July 2015 from datepicker, its getting converted as 25 July 2015 in Revise.EffectiveStartDate

when i am selecting 17 Agust2015 from datepicker, its getting converted as 16 August 2015 in Revise.EffectiveStartDate.

Why this is happening ?

Sample request from client side :

```
$scope.Revise {

Id: "TRDEV000127"
Name: "24 Contract"
EffectiveStartDate: Tue Jan 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

}
```

Comment: Is it sending the correct date from the client to server ( Inspect the request going from browser) ?

Comment: Yes. from client,its sending correct date

Comment: if 17 is converted as 14 in day part, it look as if it was showing some other part of the date time?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik: m sorry, its 16 ant not 14. corrected in the question

Comment: for more info: from client side, its sending in this format. Revise.EffectiveStartDate: Tue Jan 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: @Parashuram It might be helpful to edit your question to include a sample payload from the request.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: have added it now. thanks.

Comment: @Parashuram Do some checks with your dates always when working with specific Time Zones: 1. In server code in your DateTime values check the [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.kind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 2. Its up to you to handle as Local or Universal, on code and database. If you wanted as Local us [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ToUniversalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Parashuram Looks like your dates in code are converted as Universal Time, but first check the Kind property, if its UniversalTime then use ToLocalTime(), If its Unspecified then try ToLocalTime(), or use [SpecifyKind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.specifykind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method change it to Universal and then convert with ToLocalTime().

Comment: You should be converting your dates (GMT) to something like ISO 8601 before sending the data to your server. This way your server and database are not culture specific! Moment.js is a powerful library that can help you do this. It has support for a range of cultures and can detect the users culture based on their browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the time zone of the client and that of the server. If no time zone info or offset is included from the server the control assumes the incoming date is UTC and will subtract (or add) hours to get the local using moment.js (local time being that of the browser or client PC). This is why it will subtract 5 hours (if you are Eastern US timezone) or you wont notice it at all if you are on the other side of the GMT line as adding hours to 0 will not make a difference.

You can more accurately see this if you add hours to your time in the display in the picker.

The fix

- Ensure that moment.js translates your date/time to a UTC date/time or that without an offset when the control is created. You should be able to pass in a moment instance as an overload to the control in javascript. In your case make sure that `Revise.EffectiveStartDate` in your angular model is a moment instance and not a string and make sure the moment instance is created correctly in your angular model (or angular controller).
- There might be a fix for it too on GitHub if this is a known issue and there has been a release. Maybe you are using an older version (you never mention which version you are running). I know there was an issue at one point where the time zone info / offset included in the momentjs object was completely ignored in the picker and the local timezone info was applied to the moment object as if it were a UTC time.

You can see/search the outstanding tickets on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues)

Comment: In his example of 17 August 2016 -> 14 August 215, that's ~3 day offset, so I don't think it's a UTC adjustment thing.  His comments said this was the previous value.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - deleted and undeleted :). Looks like he meant 16 and not 14 BUT I did miss that so thank you.

Comment: so yea, I retract my comments in light of his edit. :)

Comment: @Igor is there any way to ignore time and just set the date please? actually time is not the constraint here and can be ignored.

Comment: @Parashuram - you would probably have to fork the github project and alter it to do so as the control is meant to also be able to handle the time aspect of a date/time. As I mention above I believe the easiest way is to construct the moment instance yourself (which is what the control uses internally) and use that as your model when you create your control. You could also wrap the whole thing up as your own angular directive that handles this for you so you can reuse it in your project files.

Answer (score 0):

Do some checks with your dates always when working with specific Time Zones:

1. In server code in your [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values check the [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.kind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Its up to you to handle as Local or Universal, on code and database. If you want as Local use [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ToUniversalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) appropriately.

Looks like your dates in code are converted as Universal Time, but first check the Kind property, if its Universal Time then use [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, If its Unspecified then try [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use [SpecifyKind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.specifykind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method change it to Universal and then convert with [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This side effect has nothing to do with the server. It is the client control that is not using a correctly translated momentjs instance or a defect in the control as there are outstanding issues (see the github repository open issues) so an older version of the control could also cause this behavior.